# Probability problem, MIT and Harvard

Tags: probability

A student is applying to a PhD program in Computer Sciences at
Harvard and MIT. He estimates that he has two out of three chances of being accepted at Harvard and two out of five chances at MIT. He further estimates the
probability that he will be accepted by both has probability of one to five. What
is the probability that he is accepted by MIT if he is accepted by Harvard? Is the
event "accepted by MIT" independent of the event "accepted by Harvard".

I don't understand if these are odds or probabilities

Comment: What does "ve" mean?

Comment: it's five  , sorry

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let $H=$"the student is accepted by Harvard" and $M=$"the student is accepted by MIT."

You have $P(H)=2/3,$ $P(M)=2/5$ and $P(H\cap M)=1/5.$

You are asked to get $P(M|H).$

In order to know if they are independent events you are asked to answer if $P(H\cap M)=P(H)P(M)$ or not.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yes, everything is clear now. I was just confused because I learned that if you meet something like "2 to 5" then we deal with odds.